# Does my Mac App need to apply File Access Entitlement Key for supporting Drag and Drop?

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

My Mac app lets users to drag and drop files into it, so the app will read those files. Do I need any File Access entitlement keys (e.g. `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only`) when submitting it to the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 2):

Your app does not require entitlements *for the App Store*, rather it requires them *if sandboxed*.

Turn on sandboxing for your app, e.g. in the project settings in Xcode, and then test it. If your app requires any entitlements your tests should produce errors which your code should catch, e.g. there is a failure return from a file access call. You can also watch for logged sandbox errors using Console.

When you find such a failure, determine the cause and, if it is due to lack of permissions in the sandbox, add the appropriate entitlement. Then test again.

Once your app runs in the sandbox on your system you are ready to consider submission to the App Store.

HTH